# How to move 2 or 3 character words from the end of lines in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editor

How to also move not only one charaterer, but also 2 and 3 character words from the end of the lines? ("it", "die", "yes" for ex.)

```
xxx die
xxxxxxxx
```

to

```
xxx
die xxxxxxxx
```

but not

```
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxx die
```

to

```
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxx
die
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars followed by capturing 1-3 word characters in group 1 followed by matching a newline.

In the replacement use an newline, group 1 and a space

**Find what:**

```
\h+(\w{1,3})\R
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ccr6ak/1)

**Replace with:**

`\n$1`

[image]

Comment: it works great, but it don't add space after moving word.

Comment: @Nope What do you mean by `but it don't add space after moving word` ? If you don't want to match numbers `\h+([^\W\d]{1,3})\R` https://regex101.com/r/4heZCs/1 If there should be a 3 character word before it `\b[^\W\d]{1,3}\h+([^\W\d]{1,3})\R` https://regex101.com/r/tSICgv/1